# Establish Point-to-site Azure VPN connection before Windows logon

Tags: azure, vpn

Is it possible to edit the Point-to-site Azure VPN connection to allow for authentication before logon? I want on premises computers to be able to log into the domain without having to log into the local machine first.

Comment: the whole idea of having Cloud Only AD/DC (in IaaS VM) is a bit broken IMHO. And btw is not officially supported...

Comment: I would also like to know...  let me know if you try if or get it working